# My overlay doesn't show up until press mapView in android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I have added an overlay item to my mapview but it does not show up until i press the mapview.. I tried using mapView.performlick() but still its not refreshing until i press the mapView my self... How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the magic sauce you might be missing is:

```
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Also, if someone is adding the overlays outside the UI thread (eg. async task) you can use `mapView.PostInvalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to be sure, but if you are using `ItemizedOverlay`, make sure you call `populate()` after you do add any items to it.

Comment: I have this same issue.. I call populate() every time I add an overlay to the ItemizedOverlay.. then I call it once more for good measure when I'm done adding overlays.. still I have to touch the map to make everything appear, including the zoom controls.